# Polyglossia + right-to-left language + doublespacing with setspace affects footnote spacing

Tags: xetex, footnotes, polyglossia, setspace, right-to-left

I have some Arabic text, so I use polyglossia and `\setotherlanguage{arabic}`. This however causes line spacing within footnotes to change, which looks odd, especially because the distance *between footnotes* is not changed. The same happens when I use `hebrew`, but not when using `german`.

The main text body is spaced appropriately.

This can't be intended, can it?

MWE (the examples work without actually using any Arabic):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} %remove, or change to hebrew/german to see the difference

\begin{document}
normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text\footnote{footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text}

normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text\footnote{footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text  footnote text  footnote text}
\end{document}
```

Using `arabic`:
[image]

Using `german`:
[image]

Comment: I guess this must be a bug, because I really can't think of a situation in which such a behaviour would be desireable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be solved by loading `setspace` after `polyglossia`.  It's not a bug: since `setspace` and `bidi` (loaded by `polyglossia` for RTL languages) both mess with the footnotes, you need to let `bidi` do its work and then let `setspace` do its.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal 
text normal text normal text normal 
text normal text normal text normal text normal text\footnote{footnote text 
footnote text footnote text footnote 
text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text}

normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal 
text normal text normal text normal 
text normal text normal text normal text normal text\footnote{footnote text 
footnote text footnote text footnote 
text footnote text footnote text footnote text  footnote text  footnote text}
\begin{Arabic}

العربية أكثر لغات المجموعة السامية متحدثينَ، وإحدى أكثر اللغات انتشارًا في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 422 مليون نسمة،1 ويتوزع 
متحدثوها في المنطقة المعروفة باسم الوطن العربي، بالإضافة إلى العديد من 
المناطق الأخرى المجاورة كالأحواز وتركيا وتشاد ومالي السنغال وإرتيريا. اللغة العربية ذات أهمية قصوى لدى المسلمين، فهي لغة مقدسة (لغة 
القرآن)، ولا تتم الصلاة (وعبادات أخرى) في الإسلام إلا بإتقان 
بعض من كلماتها. العربية هي أيضا لغة شعائرية رئيسية لدى عدد من الكنائس المسيحية في الوطن العربي، كما كتبت بها الكثير من أهم 
الأعمال الدينية والفكرية اليهودية في العصور الوسطى. وأثّر انتشار 
الإسلام، وتأسيسه دولاً، في ارتفاع مكانة اللغة العربية، وأصبحت لغة السياسة والعلم والأدب لقرون طويلة في الأراضي التي حكمها المسلمون، 
وأثرت العربية، تأثيرًا مباشرًا أو غير مباشر على كثير من اللغات 
الأخرى في العالم الإسلامي، كالتركية والفارسية والكردية والأوردية والماليزية والإندونيسية والألبانية وبعض اللغات الإفريقية الأخرى مثل الهاوسا 
والسواحيلية، وبعض اللغات الأوروبية وخاصةً المتوسطية منها كالإسبانية 
والبرتغالية والمالطية والصقلية. كما أنها تدرس بشكل رسمي أو غير رسمي في الدول الإسلامية والدول الإفريقية المحاذية للوطن العربي.

\footnote{\begin{Arabic}.العربية لغة رسمية في كل دول الوطن العربي إضافة إلى كونها لغة رسمية في تشاد وإريتيريا 
وإسرائيل. وهي إحدى اللغات الرسمية الست في منظمة الأمم المتحدة
\end{Arabic}}
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

I now use

```
\let\fooo\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\fooo{\setstretch{1}#1}} %polyglossia messes with footnote line spacing
```

Which works, but which I do not like, because it's a hack rather than a solution.